# Dúvida sobre requisito funcional ou não funcional

Tags: requisitos

Recentemente comecei a ler um pouco sobre requisitos funcionais e não funcionais, sobretudo as diversas classificações que um requisito não funcional pode possuir. Entretanto, ainda possuo dificuldades em certas ocasiões de diferenciar ambos.

Para ser mais específico, estou levantando requisitos para um jogo educacional, no qual os jogadores podem escolher um **modo de jogo**. Basicamente, o modo de jogo permitiria que o usuário jogasse individualmente ou em grupo.

Considerando este requisito em específico, ele seria funcional ou não funcional? E existe alguma técnica ou dica que diferencie facilmente requisitos funcionais de não funcionais?

Answer (score 1):

**Requisitos funcionais** são as tarefas de desenvolvimento que SERÃO ou PRECISAM ser DESENVOLVIDAS

- RF001 – Incluir produto
- RF002 – Alterar produto
- RF003 – Consultar produto
- RF004 – Excluir produto

**Requisitos não funcionais** entenda como premissas, exigências de desempenho e limitações, exemplo:

- RNF001 - O arquivo XML não pode exceder 500kb.
- RNF002 - O envio de arquivos não pode exceder 60 segundos.

Embora deve haver uma REGRA DE NEGÓCIO que impeça alcançar essas fronteiras e limites.

Comment: Considerando portanto que os requisitos não funcionais são limitações, o exemplo que dei de modo de jogo se enquadraria como um requisito funcional?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutamente correto!
É uma funcionalidade que precisa ser desenvolvida a qual o usuário é OBRIGADO A SELECIONAR O MODO.

Vejamos o caso abaixo:

**REQUISITO NÃO FUNCIONAL:**

**RNF001 - O arquivo XML não pode exceder 500kb.** 
Esse é um requisito imposto pelos webservers de nota fiscal eletrônica.

*E se o arquivo for maior que 500k?*

A sefaz vai responder à sua requisição normalmente, embora não aceite o arquivo e te retorne um erro. Mas você não precisou codificar nada. No máximo, vai retornar uma mensagem de erro ao usuário informando que o arquivo foi rejeitado por causa do seu tamanho.

OPCIONALMENTE, você pode especificar um REQUISITO FUNCIONAL associado a este RNF, que seria algo como:

RFxxx - A aplicação deve ser capaz de informar ao usuário que o arquivo XML está próximo/excedeu do/o limite de envio. (alguém precisa codificar isso!)